# Use strips of OSB as studs for sound-insulating (movable) wall

Tags: walls, studs, sound-proofing

I'm designing a wall/door sized 2.6*2.4 meters. It'll be made of 10mm thick OSB sheet, sandwiching 50mm of rockwool:
[image]
I consider using 50mm - wide strips of 22mm OSB as studs to fix sheets to. To avoid warping and have stability as the wall is not fixed.

The questions are:

1. Is it worth to put [something like this](http://www.texsa.com/en/pl39/productos/id326/texfon-bandas.htm?cat_39=139) between studs and the sheets to limit low-frequency sound transfer through studs?
2. Am I right about timber vs OSB being less stable?
3. How many screws do I need and what kind would suit this purpose the best?

Comment: The closed cell foam strip may help quite a bit to reduce noise at the connection points. I am not sure I understand the sandwich of son and rockwool is the wall the other side or another sheet of osb. Less screws less noise transfer

Comment: @EdBeal OSB-rockwool-OSB is all there is. Total wall thickness 70mm

Comment: OSB is cheap, and looks cheap too, and deteriorates much more readily, and really does not like water.  Consider plywood.